# вызвать программу и перенаправить ее вывод

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

всем привет, работаю под linux, пишу на Python 2.7. Пишу скрипт в котором иногда требуется вызывать стороннюю прогу `ABC`, которая в зависимости от дополнительных аргументов (`/opt/ABC var1`, например) выдает разный результат, есть необходимость перенаправить этот результат в `1.log`, как это сделать с помощью python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы эмулировать: `/opt/ABC 'var1' &> 1.log` bash-команду, не запуская баш в Питоне:

```
from subprocess import check_call, STDOUT

with open('1.log', 'wb', 0) as logfile:
    check_call(['/opt/ABC', 'var1'], stdout=logfile, stderr=STDOUT)
```

Comment: спасибо , то что нужно

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать модуль `subprocess` есть примеры в [документации](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['ls', '-1'], shell=True)
```

Потом вызвать его:

```
$ python my_scr.py

__init__.py
index.rst
interaction.py
```

Можете вызвать какой-то скрипт и сохранить результат его работы, записать в файл, вот еще [примеры](https://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/)

Comment: 1- у вас нет тут перенаправления вывода команды как в вопросе просят 2- не используйте список для команды вместе с `shell=True` -- это ошибка. 3- запускать shell тут вообще не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Помимо модуля subprocess также можно воспользоваться модулем os, в частности функцией popen (возвращает вывод), system (возвращает код возврата)

```
import os

log = open('1.log', 'w')
for line in os.popen('/opt/ABC var1'):
    log.write(line)
```

Comment: нет необходимости вывод через Питон пропускать, можно [перенаправить ввод в файл на уровне операционной системы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/769554/23044)